# Array.prototype.reduce vs a simple for loop for filtering and modifying data

Tags: javascript, performance

["Reducing Filter and Map Down to Reduce" by Elijah Manor](http://elijahmanor.com/reducing-filter-and-map-down-to-reduce/) outlines the following use case for [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

Given the following data (from the linked article):

```
var doctors = [
    { number: 1,  actor: "William Hartnell",      begin: 1963, end: 1966 },
    { number: 2,  actor: "Patrick Troughton",     begin: 1966, end: 1969 },
    { number: 3,  actor: "Jon Pertwee",           begin: 1970, end: 1974 },
    { number: 4,  actor: "Tom Baker",             begin: 1974, end: 1981 },
    { number: 5,  actor: "Peter Davison",         begin: 1982, end: 1984 },
    { number: 6,  actor: "Colin Baker",           begin: 1984, end: 1986 },
    { number: 7,  actor: "Sylvester McCoy",       begin: 1987, end: 1989 },
    { number: 8,  actor: "Paul McGann",           begin: 1996, end: 1996 },
    { number: 9,  actor: "Christopher Eccleston", begin: 2005, end: 2005 },
    { number: 10, actor: "David Tennant",         begin: 2005, end: 2010 },
    { number: 11, actor: "Matt Smith",            begin: 2010, end: 2013 },
    { number: 12, actor: "Peter Capaldi",         begin: 2013, end: 2013 }    
];
```

We can both modify and filter the data at the same time using `.reduce()` as shown below (also from the linked article):

```
doctors = doctors.reduce(function(memo, doctor) {
    if (doctor.begin > 2000) { // this serves as our `filter`
        memo.push({ // this serves as our `map`
            doctorNumber: "#" + doctor.number,
            playedBy: doctor.actor,
            yearsPlayed: doctor.end - doctor.begin + 1
        });
    }
    return memo;
}, []);
```

However, why would one prefer this over a simple `for` loop? I doubt it out-performs a simple iterating loop with similar contents (though I can't test that claim since [Jsperf is down](https://github.com/jsperf/jsperf.com/issues/18#issuecomment-113569132)).

Is there any reason (performance or otherwise) to use the `.reduce()` implementation over a simple loop, other than syntax preference?

Comment: IMO it's mainly two things: statement of intend and scope. A `reduce` is a pretty clearly defined operation and can be understood generally just by knowing that it's a reduction. A loop and separately declared variables OTOH could be anything at all. Scope is useful if you are declaring additional variables during the loop; using a `reduce` callback those variables are automatically scoped by definition and won't clutter the surrounding scope or cause unintended side effects.

Comment: Yes: with ES5 array methods you don't need to pollute the scope with iterator variables.

Comment: @deceze Written out nicely, that could be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One objective benefit of array operations like `map` or `reduce` is the inherent variable scoping and reduction of boilerplate code. Compare:

```
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
    result += arr[i];
}

// vs:

var result = arr.reduce(function (acc, val) { return acc + val; }, 0);
```

The giant loop declaration has nothing inherently to do with what you're trying to do here, it's just boilerplate code. Further, your scope now has two additional variables `i` and `length` floating around which nobody asked for, which may or may not introduce some non-obvious bugs if you're not careful.

The `reduce` code on the other hand just contains the minimum necessary parts to do what it needs to do. In something like CoffeeScript its syntax can even further be reduced to `arr.reduce (acc, val) -> acc + val`, which is pretty darn concise. And even if you'd need to create additional variables during the operation inside the loop/the callback, those won't clutter the outer scope.

Secondarily, `reduce` is a well known paradigm and serves as a good statement of intend for that code block. You don't need to parse useless auxiliary variables and figure out what they're for, you can simply break down the operation into what array is being operated on (`arr`) and what result the callback expression (`acc + val`) will produce, then extrapolate that over the entire array to know what the result will be.

*Potentially* such operations can also be better optimised by a compiler under certain circumstances, but this is mostly not seen in practice at this time I believe.

Comment: Don't forget to pass `0` to `reduce`. You don't start loops at index `1` either :-)

Comment: Not necessary for this particular operation. Read how `reduce` behaves with or without initializer...

Comment: Necessary for every empty array…

Comment: While the answer is great otherwise, I don't think the code comparison is fair, as you've pushed reduce onto a single line, while you haven't done the same for the loop. Both should follow similar styles.

Comment: @Nit Yes and no. Both are idiomatic. Loops should always be written like that, and trivial callbacks may as well be written like this. On the other hand loops should *never* be written on a single line (by most sane coding style guidelines). This goes to show another advantage that `reduce` gives you: more concise code.

Comment: @Bergi Meh, okay. Let's assume that non-empty arrays are a given here... ;-P

Comment: Only more concise if you use a very trivial function body **and** the project's style is to single line it. In any other case there's practically no difference: for example consider the code shown in the question.

Comment: @Nit Sure. I've purposefully kept the actual code to the minimal example possible to highlight the difference in **the boilerplate code**. With `reduce` there's virtually no boilerplate, with `for` the boilerplate is longer than the actual code.

Comment: @Nit All `reduce` is is a formalised abstraction around a typical pattern of a `for` loop. One of its main advantages is the reduction of boilerplate code necessary for this particular pattern.

Comment: This answer is outdated and main point of this answer is no longer valid. With introduction of let and for ... of we don't have any variables floating around.